# trying to avoid violating encapsulation

Tags: java, encapsulation, private-methods

starting some new stuff in Java and im kind of having a hard time. I feel like im on the right track just for some reason cannot find a way around the problem I am having without violating encapsulation. I have these two classes called Weight and Project. I have finished both of them but get errors in the Project class. Which include, 'toOunces', 'ounces', and 'OUNCES_IN_A_POUND'. these are private in the Weight class. I already understand that I cannot carry over private variables, methods, ect. from one class to another. I just have no clue how to go about this without violating encapsulation. below i have both the Weight class and the Project class as well as the assignment details.

I am not looking for anyone to do the work for me as I am just looking for tips, tricks, and suggestions. Also please bear with me as I am still learning the Java language and on the first week of CMIS 242.

```
public class Weight {

    //Private variables
    private static final int OUNCES_IN_A_POUND = 16;
    private int pounds;
    private double ounces;

    //A public parameterized constructor, which initializes the private variables.
    public Weight(int pounds, double ounces) {
        this.pounds = pounds;
        this.ounces = ounces;
        normalize();
    }

    //instance methods
    private double toOunces() {
        return (pounds * OUNCES_IN_A_POUND) + ounces;
    }

    private void normalize() {
        while (ounces >= OUNCES_IN_A_POUND) {
            pounds++;
            ounces -= OUNCES_IN_A_POUND;
        }
    }

    public boolean lessThan(Weight weight) {
        double thisOunces = toOunces();
        double otherOunces = weight.toOunces();
        return thisOunces < otherOunces;
    }

    public void addTo(Weight weight) {
        double thisOunces = toOunces();
        double otherOunces = weight.toOunces();
        double totalOunces = thisOunces + otherOunces;

        pounds = (int) (totalOunces / OUNCES_IN_A_POUND);
        ounces = totalOunces % OUNCES_IN_A_POUND;
        normalize();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return pounds + " pounds and " + String.format("%.2f", ounces) + " ounces";
    }
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class Project {
    private static Weight findMinimum(Weight weight1, Weight weight2, Weight weight3) {
        Weight minimumWeight = weight1;

        if (weight2.lessThan(minimumWeight)) {
            minimumWeight = weight2;
        }

        if (weight3.lessThan(minimumWeight)) {
            minimumWeight = weight3;
        }

        return minimumWeight;
    }

    private static Weight findMaximum(Weight weight1, Weight weight2, Weight weight3) {
        Weight maximumWeight = weight1;

        if (weight2.toOunces() > maximumWeight.toOunces()) {
            maximumWeight = weight2;
        }

        if (weight3.toOunces() > maximumWeight.toOunces()) {
            maximumWeight = weight3;
        }

        return maximumWeight;
    }

    private static Weight findAverage(Weight weight1, Weight weight2, Weight weight3) {
        double totalOunces = weight1.toOunces() + weight2.toOunces() + weight3.toOunces();
        double averageOunces = totalOunces / 3.0;

        int averagePounds = (int) (averageOunces / Weight.OUNCES_IN_A_POUND);
        double averageOuncesRemaining = averageOunces % Weight.OUNCES_IN_A_POUND;

        return new Weight(averagePounds, averageOuncesRemaining);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //instances of the weight class
        Weight weight1 = new Weight(11, 3);
        Weight weight2 = new Weight(7, 20);
        Weight weight3 = new Weight(14, 6);

        System.out.println("Weight 1: " + weight1.toString());
        System.out.println("Weight 2: " + weight2.toString());
        System.out.println("Weight 3: " + weight3.toString());

        Weight minimumWeight = findMinimum(weight1, weight2, weight3);
        System.out.println("The minimum weight is " + minimumWeight.toString());

        Weight maximumWeight = findMaximum(weight1, weight2, weight3);
        System.out.println("The maximum weight is " + maximumWeight.toString());

        Weight averageWeight = findAverage(weight1, weight2, weight3);
        System.out.println("The average weight is " + averageWeight.toString());
    }
}
```

link to the PDF file for the assignment details:
https://learn.umgc.edu/d2l/common/viewFile.d2lfile/Database/NzQ5OTk1NjE/Assignment1.pdf?ou=1016228

Comment: You could add a static sum method to the Weight class that takes Weights and returns the sum as a Weight.

Comment: You could return `new Weight(0, averageOunces)` from the `findAverage()` method.

Comment: The link to the assignment isn’t accessible. Stack Overflow questions should aim to be self-contained, so please copy the assignment text into the question (if that doesn’t violate academic policy)

Comment: In general, the way you avoid violating encapsulation is by adding functionality to the encapsulated class. You could add a method to `Weight` that averages itself with another `Weight`. You can average three weights by taking the average of the first two, and then averaging that with the third. I don’t know if that’s what the instructor wants, though.

Comment: Typically, when resolve is required from an alternate source you would create an _[accessor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)_ method.  So in this case, _"getPoundsPerOunce"_, and _"getToOunces"_.  If this appears to be typical for your design pattern, you could try creating an _[interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)_ or _[abstract class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)_, for which you can more easily maintain what data is for local use, and what is for an alternate source.

Comment: @Reilas Neither of those is correct.  `toOunces()` is correct as it is, because it’s not a property of a Weight instance, it’s operation that’s performed on a Weight instance.  Pounds per ounce is not a property of any one Weight instance, so it should be static.  The correct solution here is either a static `sum` method like Hulk suggested, or a non-static `add` or `plus` method that takes one Weight argument and returns a new Weight instance.

Answer (score 0):

OUNCES_IN_A_POUND is private and should remain private.  This is why the Project class cannot access it.

You are on the right track:  this is indeed a matter of encapsulation.  What you want to do is encapsulate *all* mathematical operations, inside public methods of the Weight class itself.

So, instead of this:

```
double totalOunces = weight1.toOunces() + weight2.toOunces() + weight3.toOunces();
double averageOunces = totalOunces / 3.0;

int averagePounds = (int) (averageOunces / Weight.OUNCES_IN_A_POUND);
double averageOuncesRemaining = averageOunces % Weight.OUNCES_IN_A_POUND;
```

You want to write something like this:

```
Weight sum = new Weight(weight1);
sum.addTo(weight2);
sum.addTo(weight3);

return sum.divideBy(3);
```

This achieves encapsulation by having the Weight class manage all computational operations.  Callers never need to break the encapsulation by manipulating its numeric properties directly.

As you can see, a couple additions to Weight are needed:

```
/**
 * Makes a copy of an existing Weight instance.
 *
 * @param other non-null Weight instance to be copied
 */
public Weight(Weight other) {
    // ...
}

/**
 * Divides this Weight by the given factor.
 *
 * @param divisor amount by which this Weight will be divided
 */
public void divideBy(double divisor) {
    // ...
}
```

I leave it to you to implement that constructor and that method.

As a final note, you may want to consider renaming your `addTo` method to just `add`.  The method is not adding anything to the argument and is not altering the argument in any way;  rather, it is using the argument to add to the instance’s own value.